# SystemD restarting DHCPD error: Job for dhcpcd@wlan0.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, wifi, dhcp, dhcpcd

I have Arch linux on Lenovo thinkpad. I have `Linux 5.13.13-arch1-1`. In recent time, my wifi just stops working some time after start. Only solution to make it work again is reboot. When I run `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd@wlan0.service` I get:

```
Job for dhcpcd@wlan0.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status dhcpcd@wlan0.service" and "journalctl -xeu dhcpcd@wlan0.service" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status dhcpcd@wlan0.service`:

```
× dhcpcd@wlan0.service - dhcpcd on wlan0
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sat 2021-08-28 01:45:52 CEST; 18s ago
    Process: 19655 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -w wlan0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 7ms
```

Output of `sudo journalctl -xeu dhcpcd@wlan0.service`:

```
░░ The unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
srp 28 01:24:08 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on wlan0.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 83 and the job result is failed.
srp 28 01:45:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on wlan0...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1353.
srp 28 01:45:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: dhcpcd@wlan0.service: Can't open PID file /run/dhcpcd/wlan0.pid (yet?) after start: >
srp 28 01:45:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: dhcpcd@wlan0.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ The unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
srp 28 01:45:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on wlan0.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ A start job for unit dhcpcd@wlan0.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1353 and the job result is failed.
```

What should I do to prevent this from happening ?
Thank you for help

Comment: did you try another wifi network? or is it specific to your wifi only? if your wifi, did you try another system (the same computer with liveusb)?

Comment: Yes I did. Issue is same on every wifi I tried.